# How can I write a class like Android ContentValues?

Tags: android

My question is that: Android SDK has a class was named ContentValues.
That class keeps our values to save them to DB easily.

But it has these methods:

```
put(String key, Integer value)
put(String key, Float value)
put(String key, Byte value)  etc
```

so this means it can take and keep Integer, Byte, Float, Double...etc.

I wonder how this class can keep all these different-typed variables?

I know how to use it. I wonder how can we write a class like that

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean [how it's implemented](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/content/ContentValues.java)? Or how it's used? For that, check the NotePad sample app that came with the SDK.

Comment: Beat me to it by 10 sec. +1 for both implementation and example of use.

Comment: @bmavus and he gave you a link to the place where the code for ContentValues is displayed and explained. Basically what it does is it holds a HashMap<String, Object> and when getAsInteger is called a check is performed to see if the called object is really an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the whole tutorial, but I think it might help you:

[Java Serialization Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)